# Logrotate command block explanation

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have the following logrotate command block -

```
/a/b/file.log{
size 200M
create 0664 root root
rotate 10
compress
datext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
}
```

Can someone elaborate the meaning of the above block?

Especially the statements -

- create 0664 root root
- datext
- dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s

Also any good resources for logrotate command blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the Linux manual [`logrotate(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/logrotate.8.html#CONFIGURATION_FILE_DIRECTIVES). It should mention all the directives in the question.

By the way, it’s `dateext` for date extension. Not data-extension.

Comment: Ok sure. One question - Would specifying the directory as - /var/log/basedir/*/* logrotate all the files in all the subfolders of basedir?

Comment: @DawsonSmith It would, but it would also attempt to rotate the rotated logs. You would end up with rotated logs, rotated rotated logs, rotated rotated rotated (etc.) logs.  Don't do that.

Comment: Not able to understand the difference between compress and nocompress. If I have two files a.log ( which is the original file) and a.log.1.gz which is the rotated archived version of it, how would compress and nocompress work for both of them?

Comment: You should get `a.log.1.gz` because compression is enabled with `compress` in your example. You get `a.log.1` instead if you disable compression with `nocompress`.

Comment: Please see if you can answer this one - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685105/understanding-the-difference-between-rotate-alone-and-rotate-with-compress-in-lo

Comment: @they Please try the above question

Comment: @FranklinYu Please try the above question