# Understanding the difference between rotate alone and rotate with compress in logrotate

Tags: logrotate

The below block has no compress statement -

```
/a/b/file.log{
size 200M
create 0664 root root
rotate 10
datext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
}
```

This one has a compress statement -

```
/a/b/file.log{
size 200M
create 0664 root root
rotate 10
compress
datext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
}
```

This one has a nocompress statement -

```
/a/b/file.log{
size 200M
create 0664 root root
rotate 10
nocompress
datext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d-%s
}
```

What is the difference between the above three scenarios? How will logrotate functioning be different in each of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Using `compress` compresses the rotated log.
- Using `nocompress` would not compress the rotated log file.
- Not using `compress` nor `nocompress` would not change the default setting of compression or no compression.

The default setting for compression could be set at the start of the `logrotate` configuration file as a global option, as is done in the sample configuration in the `logrotate.conf` manual:

```
# sample logrotate configuration file
compress

/var/log/messages {
    rotate 5
    weekly
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP syslogd
    endscript
}

"/var/log/httpd/access.log" /var/log/httpd/error.log {
    rotate 5
    mail recipient@example.org
    size 100k
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP httpd
    endscript
}

/var/log/news/* {
    monthly
    rotate 2
    olddir /var/log/news/old
    missingok
    postrotate
        kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/inn.pid)
    endscript
    nocompress
}

~/log/*.log {}
```

The manual says:

> The first few lines set global options; in the example, logs are compressed after
> they  are  rotated.  [...]

It goes on to say that the first two sections (and the last) rotates `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/httpd/access.log`,  `/var/log/httpd/error.log` and `~/log/*.log` with compression (due to the global `compress` option).  The `/var/log/news/*` files are rotated *without* compression due to `nocompress`.

If neither `compress` nor `nocompress` is set as a global option, and not used in a configuration section for a log file or set of log files, then `logrotate` would *not* compress the rotated log files affected by that configuration section.

Comment: So nocompress and not specifying anything means the same thing?

Comment: @DawsonSmith Logs are not compressed by default. `nocompress` ensures no compression.

Comment: note that logrotate's `compress` option is useful on filesystems that **don't** have built-in transparent compression, like ext4 or xfs.  It should be disabled on filesystems that **do** have built-in compression (e.g. zfs)....gzip can compress better than lz4, but there's little or no space saving if the text is already compressed, in fact it wastes space if you have snapshots of both the old uncompressed log file and the new rotated & compressed log file. and zfs can optionally use gzip or zstd anyway instead of the default of lzjb or lz4.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by the others.

You have to check the default value. This is mendatory not only for `logrotate` but for other configs as well.

Manpages for `logrotate` describe this as follow:

> `compress`
>
> Old versions of log files are compressed **with `gzip(1)` by default**. See also `nocompress`.
>
> `nocompress`
>
> Old versions of log files are not compressed.  See also `compress`.

Comment: The words "by default" in the manual refers to the default method of compression if `compress` is used.  It does not imply that compression is done by default. In fact, the manual does not say whether compression is done by default or not, but it's easy to test and find that compression is _not_ done by default.